# Showing the set {n+1/n} is closed but {1/n} is not

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A=\{n +1/n : n=2,3,...\}$ . I want to show that this is closed.

If we show $A^c$ is open then $A$ is closed. Here $A^c = (\cup_{i=2}^{\infty} (i +1/i, i+1 + 1/(i+1))) \cup (-\infty,2.5)$ which is an arbitaru collection of open sets which is open. This A is closed.

The only doubt I have with this style of proof is that it seems to work for $A=\{1/n\}$ as well.
Because $A^c = (\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} (1/(i+1), 1/i)) \cup (-\infty,0] \cup (1,\infty) $ <s>which is also a collection of open sets. But we know A is not closed here. Why does the argument fail here?</s>

Comment: You need to be more careful with the kind of decomposition in open subsets you are writing. In the first case you are missing some of the points in $A^c$. The second case is worse, because you are still missing points in $A^c$, but your union of open sets also contains every points in $A$. You can easily fix your first decomposition to prove that $A$ is indeed closed. For the second subset try to find an open set containing $0$ which does not intersect $A$. Your failure to do so will be a proof that $A^c$ is not open

Comment: Your decompositions are wrong, is easier for this kind of subsets, to see if they contain all their limit points

Comment: Is my decomposition right now?

Comment: The elements of $A$ are $\dfrac{n + 1}{n}$  or $n+\dfrac1n$?

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- We assume $A=\{n+\dfrac 1n: n=2,3...\}$ as subset of $\mathbb R$ provided with the usual topology.

The complement $A^c$ is obviously the union of open intervals $]n+\dfrac1n,(n+1)+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)}[$ and $]\infty,2+\dfrac12[$ so it is open.

For $B=\{\dfrac1n: n=2,3,....\}$ is in its "right" part a union of open intervals including $]\dfrac12,+\infty[$. However the limit $0$ of $B$ is not an element of $B$ so the "left" part of $B^c$ cannot be defined as an open interval (if you take $I_{n+1}=]-\infty, \dfrac{1}{n+1}[\space\space$ then $\dfrac{1}{n+2}\in I_{n+1}$ so $I_{n+1}$ is not a part of $B^c$).

Comment: A very easy way to see that $B$ is not closed is to note that the closure of $B$ contains the limit point $0$ which does not belong to $B$.